# fetching data with axios and then displaying it

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios

I have managed to find the source of the data, now I want to display the data. I've commented out my method as it keeps saying that I can not use map. What is the best way for me to do this? The plan is display the data in separate cards.

```
function Data() {
    const [Music, setMusic] = useState({});

    useEffect(() => {
        axios.get('https://itunes.apple.com/us/rss/topalbums/limit=100/json')
            .then((data) => {
                setMusic(data.data.feed.entry);
                console.log(data.data.feed.entry);
            })
            .catch((err) => console.log(err));
    }, []);

    return (
        <div>
            {/* <h2>Album List</h2>
            <ul className='albums'>
                {Music.map((Music) => {
                    const { label, image_url, price, title, artist} = Music;
                    return(
                        <li key={id}>
                            <img src={''} alt={'error'} />
                            <h4>{name}</h4>

                        </li>
                    )
                })}
            </ul> */}
        </div>
    );
}
```

Comment: can you please make demo on codesandbox

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/naughty-easley-3992v
Have look here bro! may be there are some issues with array destructuring that i do not understand

Answer (score 1):

You should use `setState([])`. Now, before fetch is completed, you make call `{}.map` which is undefined.

Answer (score 1):

The map function can only be used in arrays. Cannot be used on objects. You should change your state definition to.

```
const [Music, setMusic] = useState([]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Just change type of your default state from Object-{} to Array-[]

```
const [Music, setMusic] = useState([]);
```

and destructure id as well because you are accessing without that

```
 <ul className="albums">
        {Music.map(Music => {
          const { id, label, image_url, price, title, artist } = Music;
          return (
            <li key={id.attributes.id}>
              <img src={""} alt={"error"} />
              <h4>{name}</h4>
            </li>
          );
        })}
      </ul>
```

Improved [Live demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-xpxbfs?file=src/App.js)

> Before using `{ id, label, image_url, price, title, artist }`, make sure to check properly because some of these fields are object

Comment: thanks, how would I access the data in the objects?

Comment: @SeanMarc You have to follow similar to key={id.attributes.id} for other fields after checking.

Comment: can you please provide an example as I am still not receiving any data on my initial question. I keep getting the error " each child in a list should have a unique key prop"